the FARO scanner will be triggered when the data collection is stopped

The development of the FARO scanner will be triggered when the data collection is stopped

This is a pop-up window for my program that prompts Windows 10
the is SDK API link :
The general interface to connect and communicate with a FARO Focus laser scanner
https://developer.faro.com/scene_api/class_s_c_e_n_e___a_p_i_1_1_l_s_scanner.html
how to try to solve the problem.
the is api fun:
void    stopScan ()
Stops a running scan.

Try to imagine yourself as someone who knows nothing about your project, reading this. Do you think you have provided enough information for that person to be able to help you? I personally don't. For example; what is "the FARO scanner"? What does "the is api fun: void stopScan () Stops a running scan" even mean?
